# Why is my SESSION array OK on one page but empty on another?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a class that sets various session variables. After I set the session variable I do a var dump of SESSION and get an output of them all. all good so far. Then I navigate to another page.

```
session_start(); // i call this right after opening the php tag
var_dump($_SESSION); // i call this after setting the variables
```

and it's empty this time?

**Setting my sessions**

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
           $_SESSION['atid'] = $row['autotaskid'];
           $_SESSION['bmsid'] = $row['bmsid'];
           $_SESSION['shavlikid'] = $row['shavlikid'];
           $_SESSION['cpid'] = $row['cpid'];
    }
```

**Trying to use the variables on another page**

```
$autotaskid = $_SESSION['atid'];
    $tsql = "SELECT COUNT(tblBackupArchive.StatusID) AS total, tblBackupArchive.StatusID ".
            "FROM tblBackupArchive INNER JOIN ".
            "tblBackup ON tblBackupArchive.BackupID = tblBackup.BackupID ".
            "GROUP BY tblBackupArchive.StatusID, tblBackup.ClientID ".
            "HAVING (tblBackup.ClientID = " . $autotaskid . ")";
```

Results in

```
Undefined index: atid in C:\Program File...
```

I've made sure I'm issuing the start_session(); function before any other code is run on every page that uses them.

**Another important point**: the php page that calls the method setting the variables within an iframe. when i open the page in a new tab/window it sets the sessions correctly. It's almost like the main window has session variables and then each iframe keeps it own seperate.

Any ideas?

Billy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any ideas?

Yes. You have to learn to debug your code.
As you can see, your question cannot be answered out of guesswork. So, it's time for handwork.

- First make sure you can see any error occurred. Just add an intentional one and see. If you see no errors you have to turn it on.
- then make a testing script to see if your sessions do work

  ```
  <? 
  session_start(); 
  if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
  echo "Refreshed ".$_SESSION['counter']++." times.<br>
  <a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.session_name().'='.session_id().">refresh</a>"; 
  ?>
  ```

if it works, make it to use cookies

```
<? 
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;
echo "Refreshed ".$_SESSION['counter']++." times.<br>
<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">refresh</a>"; 
?>
```

if it works too, you have to check your code.
Print out variables, reduce code, etc

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestions. I added the counter test you posted. The interesting thing is that after trying that test, then navigating to the page where my sessions are set, then moving to the other page, instead of seeing the session array empty I now see counter. The issue must then be with the code setting the sessions. I set the sessions in a method used only by the first page. can it be they are being destroyed after being used?

Comment: @Jonesy the code you posted here is all right. Though I'd make it with single statement `$_SESSION['savedata'] = $row;` and then use it as `$autotaskid = $_SESSION['savedata']['atid'];` sometimes it can help. if not - you have to add var_dump($_SESSION); in as many places as you can

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that the php app is accessed via an iframe. When I do the same in a new window everything is ok. Is there a different set of session variables for each iframe?

Comment: @Jonesy iframes has nothing to do with PHP or sessions. Sessions are domain related.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why did you rollback this?

Comment: @kelunik because it's legitimate PHP code, and it's only matter of coding style. Please do not edit my answers to meet your personal tastes. Any syntax error or whatever else essential fix are still welcome.

Comment: @YourCommonSense This is not only code style, it requires [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to be enabled.

Comment: @kelunik Whatever. I'll be much obliged if you leave my humble answer alone.

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing the session ids. If you get a different session id across the calls, the session management is not correctly set up.

I.e. your code may rely on session ids stored in cookies, but that option is disabled (see your `php.ini`).

As a debugging measure you may use "transparent session ids" (they're concatenated to any link), but not for production code.

Comment: Hi, I posted this question a while back and ended up reinstalling wamp. I've run into it again and started a new question. Please can you have a look at it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358525/php-session-variables-not-being-maintaned

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first code block, it sounds like you might be calling `session_start()` **after** you've tried to set the `$_SESSION` variables. You must call `session_start()` first! I could be wrong, in which case I apologise. But based on the above code snippet it could well be your problem!

Comment: sorry that's just me confusion people, I cut out some code there. I actually call session_start BEFORE anything else. Right after opening the php tag. thanks though

Comment: In which case I'm not sure!  
Could be to do with your environment. I've never worked with local PHP on Windows before.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `session_close()` where you should be, then are you accidentally destroying the session? Perhaps a few too many `session_destroy()` calls?

And by a few too many I mean one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. You execute `session_start()` before you set or get a session variable. (If the server is configured to autostart sessions, this is not necessary.)
2. Both scripts live on the same (sub)domain. (It's not enough for pages to be on the same server to share a session, they also have to belong to the same (sub)domain.)

Answer (score 0):

```
I was facing the same problem. One impotent thin that session must be defined as first line of the code...even no single line space from top. Second the session variable must be defined at global level first. Normally arrays are fetched with in a loops from MySql data. And loop variables are not available at global level. So it must be defined at global level. It solved my problem.

<?PHP
    session_start();
    $items = array();
    $_SESSION['item'] = $items;
?>
```

Now do whatever you want to do...