# PHP session is not working

Tags: php, session, iframe, wamp

I am working with wamp2.0 - PHP 5.3, apache 2.2.11 but my sessions are not storing data.

I have a page that accepts a parameter, which (simplified version) I wanna store in a session, so when I come to

```
http://www.example.com/home.php?sessid=db_session_id
```

The script looks like:

```
session_start();

$sessid = @$_GET['sessid'];
if ($sessid) {
  $_SESSION['sessid'] = $sessid;
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and outputs:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "db_session_id" }
```

which is fine, but then, when I go to [link](http://www.example.com/home.php) (without the sessid parameter) the `$_SESSION` array is empty. I've event tried to comment the `$_SESSION['sessid'] = $sessid;` line before going to the page without the parameter, but still it didin't work.

I've checked the `session_id()` output and the session id remains the same.

Session settings from phpinfo()

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   c:/wamp/tmp c:/wamp/tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

**EDIT:**

> The sessions are deleted by an iframe. I don't know why, but when
>   commented, the sessions work fine. Thing is, the iframe has to stay
>   there (which of course is bad, but I can't do anything about it).
>   Well...do you know about any workarounds to get the sessions working
>   with an iframe?

Comment: Is the `COOKIE` set in the browser?

Comment: if you mean the `$_COOKIE` variable, then yes, it is set

Comment: Wait, am i the only one here noticing that this script is completely wrong for author purpose and it works as it should actually? If you don't set $_GET['sessid'] neither $sessid is set and the if statement doesn't run.

Comment: Well...first I go to a page, where the `sessid` IS set, so there also should the session variable be set (which happens). But the data does not remain there.

Comment: Ok, now i got the meaning of this question. Eeverything seems to be fine so either you have some strange bugs into your software or your simplified version has also deleted your problem because i run that script and it works fine to me. Have you tried running the script you posted? It is not a session problem, but a script problem imho. Also, is your $_SESSION array empty or contains an empty string? It is not the same...

Comment: Seems like you are right. The simplified version indeed does work fine. Even the almost non-simplified version does work. Gotta look for the problem somewhere else. But it behaves very strangely. When find  out what's going on, I will post where the problem was.

Comment: Very strange...I commented the whole script (except for the session setting part obv.) - it worked...then uncommented step by step, but it didn't change anything and it worked all the time, so now I have completely unchanged script that works...o.O But I bet it's gonna stop working soon

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I was about to post an answer, but I didn't want to if you have already figured it out. If you still need help, please reply and also tell me which browser you are testing with.

Comment: TBH, I don't really remember, it's more than year and a half ago since the question was asked but I suppose I got it working but don't remember the sollution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame can access the session only if it's relative to the same domain. For example:

```
<? 
$_SESSION["foo"]="foo"; 
?><html> 
 <body> 
  <iframe src ="test.php" width="200" height="200"></iframe> 
 </body> 
</html> 
<? 
print_r($_SESSION); 
?>
```

Should work outside and inside the iframe. If your still having problems try:

```
 <?php  session_start();

    $sessid = $_GET['sessid'];
    if (isset($sessid) && $sessid != "" && $sessid != NULL) {
      $_SESSION['sessid'] = $sessid;
    }
    print_r($_SESSION);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question, but I came here with the same problem. As the question was not answered, here it comes what I've found.

I had a similar problem and in my case the problem was I was not calling `session_start()` in all the pages where the session was used. I thought I should call it only in the "login" page, but this is not true.

Besides, remember that `session_start()` must be called before the `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You must call the command `session_start();` in each page. It worked for me. You must also call this before any output (html, output, even whitespace) is sent to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a similar issue, I find this to be a fairly worthwhile test. Run a few request in the browser and see what you get.

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_SESSION);
```

To the author: Your last comment mentions that your script is working - good for you. If it breaks then try out the bit of code above and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Today I spent about four hours with $_SESSION not being saved at the server.
It turned out to be a server issue. The system (Windows 2003, IIS 6) used the Windows default temporary folder C:\Windows\Temp\ to store the session. It created it but it was empty.

For some reason it just stopped to work (there was no problem before). My best guess that it reached some limit or the folder simply contained too many files.
I sorted it out by setting session.save_path to a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess from whats happening there that your session isn't been stored. Is your session.save_path -> c:/wamp/tmp a writable (uncheck read only in properties) folder? Is apache being run as an administrator or some level with sufficient permissions to write to that folder in services in the administrator tools in control panel?

Actually, check this: [PHP session vars not being maintained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358525/php-session-variables-not-being-maintaned). Essentially, run session_id() on that page twice and compare the session ids. If they are different then your browser is not accepting session cookies.

EDIT: Didn't realize you already did that. ^

This might help. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857081/why-is-my-session-array-ok-on-one-page-but-empty-on-another/4358557) <--- Look at the second suggestion/answer with the debugging code for session.

Comment: Everything is ok. The session files are created propperly. The last file contains `sessid|s:0:"";`, so it is written but without the data. It's strange

Comment: Could you run var_dump($_SESSION." ".$_COOKIE); just right after the session_start?

Comment: added var dumps to the original question. gonna take a look at the link now

Comment: As much as I would hate suggesting this, but use var_dump(session_register('sessid', 'value'))

Comment: `var_dump(session_register('sessid', 'value'))` prints `bool(true)`

Comment: setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000 ); session_destroy(); - Get rid of the session and refresh twice with the original code

Comment: Last suggestions: error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of that script. To see if there is any error being generated that you can't see and check your error_log file for php. I have nothing else to offer.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

You have to put something inside the $_SESSION global array for it to register anything, otherwise, it's empty...

Since you are testing the existence of sessid to add it to $_SESSION, $_SESSION remains empty.

Try something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['sessid'] = 123456789;
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: if I do var_dump on `$_SESSION` after the `if ($sessid) ...` the variables are stored there, but are not held inside when I go the other page without parameter

Comment: This one misunderstand your question as i did. He FIRST set the sessid parameter and the session should register the variable, THEN it goes in the same page without setting sessid and the variable should be there.

Answer (score 0):

...

It could be because you are not using a domain per se? In your question, you use example.com, however you are developing on your local machine. I assume you are using localhost.

You should know that one cannot set cookies on localhost, see for example: [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

Have you tried your code on another host?

http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2008/12/21/php-sessions-on-localhost/

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it is the cause of your problem (the error-suppressing `@` seems a bit out-of-place here...), but I would simplify a bit.

So instead of:

```
$sessid = @$_GET['sessid'];
if ($sessid) {
  $_SESSION['sessid'] = $sessid;
}
```

I would use:

```
if (isset($_GET['sessid']))
{
  $_SESSION['sessid'] = $_GET['sessid'];
}
```

By the way, I would also do some input-checking on `$_GET['sessid']` to make sure it only contains the characters allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, in my case the problem was that my /home was **full**. As i was using fcgi running inside /home/mydomian/fcgi-bin/php7.3.fcgi the script **couldn't write sessions on disk**. After i free same space and restart server the problem solved.