# Why is my PHP session array disappearing between page reloads?

Tags: php, session-variables

I can't figure out why my PHP session array disappears between page loads. The following code makes session_start() available on each page load:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) {
    $gmeta_query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str( $gmeta_query_string, $gmeta_query_array );
    var_dump($gmeta_query_array);
    foreach ( $gmeta_query_array as $key => $value ) {
        $_SESSION[ 'gmeta_query_array' ][$key] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump( $_SESSION );
echo session_id();
?>
```

Thinking perhaps it could be my server, here are some test URLs. This first link creates a session array and print its out, the second does prints an empty session array. Code is the same on both pages.

http://barbadospropertylist.com/wp-content/plugins/gravitymeta/test.php?name=value

http://barbadospropertylist.com/wp-content/plugins/gravitymeta/test.php

And here's a link to the PHP info: http://www.barbadospropertylist.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Comments are not meant for real time collaboration. Please take this to chat.  You should update your question with the relevant details and not put those details in comments.  It's hard for new users to find information in comments.

Comment: I don't even see the comments anymore, did you delete them?

Answer (score 1):

The same type of question was asked by another user in SO, and got it resolved.

Please check if it can help you
[PHP session is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614671/php-sessions-not-working)

Can you print the session_id, whether it's not changed on each page load?

Comment: I have tested the same code in my local and it's working fine. Problem is somewhere else, apart from code.

Comment: Agreed, must be my server. Will post this question with the hosting company.